# Get value of checked radio button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have some questions with answers. I want to store the checked off answer in a variable. Each answer is as a radio button. For example:

```
<h4 class='ques1'>Question one here here</h4>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> answer 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> answer 2
        </label>
    </div>

 <h4 class='ques2'>Question two here here</h4>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> answer 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> answer 2
        </label>
    </div>
```

Then I have variables set up to store the checked answer….

```
var ques1Answer, ques2Answer;
```

I'm not sure if you need to query the label tag or the input tag to get the value. But this is what I've tried:

```
$('h4.ques1 div.checkbox label input').on('change', function(){
     ques1Answer = $(this).val();
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean each answer is as a radio button? You're not using radio buttons you're using checkboxes....

Comment: Your checkboxes have no value attribute.

Comment: OP should clarify his question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of your selector is wrong `'h4.ques1 div.checkbox label input'`
 the `DIV` is not a child of `h4.ques1` so use:

```
$('div.checkbox label input')
```

if you use `.val()` that implies that actually you have an **value attribute** otherwise you'd better assign some `name` attributes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Question-A-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Question-A-2">
```

so even if you get the `"on"` / `"off"` (default values) you'll always know what's the `name` entity those values are referring to.

---

Worth noting that *if only one answer is possible-per-question* than you might want to use **Radio Buttons instead**

```
<input type="radio" name="Question-A" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="Question-A" value="2">
```

in that case it makes sense to hold inside your `var`s only one value-per-question.

Than wrap all your questionnary inside a `<form>` and use `.serialize()` fo get all the answers:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 alert( $("form#questionnary").serialize() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="questionnary">
  <h4 class='ques1'>Question one here</h4>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Question-A" value="1"> answer 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Question-A" value="2"> answer 2
    </label>
  </div>

  <h4 class='ques2'>Question two here</h4>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Question-B" value="1"> answer 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Question-B" value="2"> answer 2
    </label>
  </div>
</form>


<button>TEST RESULTS</button>
```